# I get this error: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1868, 32, 1)

Tags: python, pandas, lstm

I'm trying to make an LSTM based AI that makes music. But I keep getting this error and idk what it means. Here is the code:

```
networkInputShaped,networkOutputShaped = oversample(network_input,network_output, sequence_length=seqlength)
```

I am following this tutorial: https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/how-to-generate-music-using-machine-learning-72360ba4a085

I have tried to fix it by googleing this error, looking at the source code the tutorial provides(which was a bit different to the code in the tutorial for some reason), winging it, but it won't work.

I'm a beginner, so I really don't know the expected output.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is for this problem is by making the shape of `network_input` and `network_output` same. To do it change the `sequence_length` variable in **`prepare_sequences`** function to 254 and also change the `sequence_length` argument of the **`oversample`** to 507.

Here is the changes I made to run it successfully.

**prepare_sequences function**

```py
def prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab):
    """ Prepare the sequences used by the Neural Network """
    sequence_length = 254

    # Get all unique pitchnames
    pitchnames = sorted(set(item for item in notes))
    numPitches = len(pitchnames)

     # Create a dictionary to map pitches to integers
    note_to_int = dict((note, number) for number, note in enumerate(pitchnames))

    network_input = []
    network_output = []

    # create input sequences and the corresponding outputs
    for i in range(0, len(notes) - sequence_length, 1):
        # sequence_in is a sequence_length list containing sequence_length notes
        sequence_in = notes[i:i + sequence_length]
        # sequence_out is the sequence_length + 1 note that comes after all the notes in
        # sequence_in. This is so the model can read sequence_length notes before predicting
        # the next one.
        sequence_out = notes[i + sequence_length]
        # network_input is the same as sequence_in but it containes the indexes from the notes
        # because the model is only fed the indexes.
        network_input.append([note_to_int[char] for char in sequence_in])
        # network_output containes the index of the sequence_out
        network_output.append(note_to_int[sequence_out])

    # n_patters is the length of the times it was iterated 
    # for example if i = 3, then n_patterns = 3
    # because network_input is a list of lists
    n_patterns = len(network_input)

    # reshape the input into a format compatible with LSTM layers
    # Reshapes it into a n_patterns by sequence_length matrix
    print(len(network_input))
    
    network_input = numpy.reshape(network_input, (n_patterns, sequence_length, 1))
    # normalize input
    network_input = network_input / float(n_vocab)

    # OneHot encodes the network_output
    network_output = np_utils.to_categorical(network_output)

    return (network_input, network_output)


n_vocab = len(set(notes))
network_input, network_output = prepare_sequences(notes,n_vocab)
n_patterns = len(network_input)
pitchnames = sorted(set(item for item in notes))
numPitches = len(pitchnames)
```

**oversample function**

```py
def oversample(network_input,network_output,sequence_length=15):

  n_patterns = len(network_input)
  # Create a DataFrame from the two matrices
  new_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(network_input),pd.DataFrame(network_output)],axis=1)

  # Rename the columns to numbers and Notes
  new_df.columns = [x for x in range(sequence_length+1)]
  new_df = new_df.rename(columns={sequence_length:'Notes'})

  print(new_df.tail(20))
  print('###################################################')
  print(f'Distribution of notes in the preoversampled DataFrame: {new_df["Notes"].value_counts()}')
  # Oversampling
  oversampled_df = new_df.copy()
  #max_class_size = np.max(oversampled_df['Notes'].value_counts())
  max_class_size = 700
  print('Size of biggest class: ', max_class_size)

  class_subsets = [oversampled_df.query('Notes == ' + str(i)) for i in range(len(new_df["Notes"].unique()))] # range(2) because it is a binary class

  for i in range(len(new_df['Notes'].unique())):
    try:
      class_subsets[i] = class_subsets[i].sample(max_class_size,random_state=42,replace=True)
    except:
      print(i)

  oversampled_df = pd.concat(class_subsets,axis=0).sample(frac=1.0,random_state=42).reset_index(drop=True)

  print('###################################################')
  print(f'Distribution of notes in the oversampled DataFrame: {oversampled_df["Notes"].value_counts()}')

  # Get a sample from the oversampled DataFrame (because it may be too big, and we also have to convert it into a 3D array for the LSTM)
  sampled_df = oversampled_df.sample(n_patterns,replace=True) # 99968*32 has to be equals to (99968,32,1)

  print('###################################################')
  print(f'Distribution of notes in the oversampled post-sampled DataFrame: {sampled_df["Notes"].value_counts()}')

  # Convert the training columns back to a 3D array
  network_in = sampled_df[[x for x in range(sequence_length)]]
  network_in = np.array(network_in)
  # network_in = np.reshape(network_input, (n_patterns, sequence_length, 1))
  network_in = network_in / numPitches
  print(network_in.shape)
  print(sampled_df['Notes'].shape)
  # Converts the target column into a OneHot encoded matrix
  network_out = pd.get_dummies(sampled_df['Notes'])
  print(network_out.shape)

  return network_in,network_out

print(network_input[...,0].shape)
print(network_output.shape)
networkInputShaped,networkOutputShaped = oversample(network_input[...,0],network_output,sequence_length=507)
networkOutputShaped = np_utils.to_categorical(network_output)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, But I now seem to have this error:
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 508 elements, new values have 255 elements 
can you please help?
I copy pasted you code into mine. So I have pretty much the same as you do.